# How to add testers to existing wp7 beta app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I submitted an app to the new windows phone beta marketplace with one tester live id.

Now I want to add some more testers. I can't see any way of updating an existing beta app on the app hub.

Any ideas?

Comment: you should ask on the app hub forums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the App Hub is behaving itself I managed to find out how to do this.

Click View all submitted apps

Set View to Submitted

Click App to update

Click Update Testers

Comment: I've just submitted my app for beta testing but can't see this option. Was there a delay before this was available?